# Django and PostgreSQL sequence for primary key autoincrement

Tags: django, postgresql

I have the following table and sequence in my postgresql-8.4 database:

```
CREATE TABLE complexobjectpy
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  the_geom geometry,
  semcat integer,
  CONSTRAINT complexobjectpy_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_the_geom CHECK (st_ndims(the_geom) = 2),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_the_geom CHECK (st_srid(the_geom) = 900913)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE complexobjectpy OWNER TO tss;

CREATE SEQUENCE seq_complexobjectpy
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
  CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE seq_complexobjectpy OWNER TO tss;
```

The following is instead my Django model:

```
class Complexobjectpy(models.Model):
    the_geom = models.GeometryField(srid=900913)
    semcat = models.IntegerField()
    objects = models.GeoManager()
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'complexobjectpy'
```

Performing the following query:

```
myObj = Complexobjectpy(semcat=50, the_geom=geometryMerged.wkt)
myObj.save(using='u1')
```

I get the error:

```
IntegrityError: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

Why I get this? Reading the documentation I was expecting that the id value would be chosen automatically using the sequence...

Comment: Did you create the table using syncdb? In my DB all ID fields are serial: 
id serial NOT NULL,

Comment: No, I have created the db table and the model separately.

Comment: It's been quite some time, but if someone else comes around, you should add [`managed = False`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#managed) in your model's meta options when you create the tables yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I am providing this as an answer. The datatype serial in postgres is an auto incremental four-byte integer. If you change your id from integer to serial this would work.

```
 id serial NOT NULL
```

Read more: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype.html

Comment: Yeah, now it works! The solution was indeed to change "integer" with "serial".