# default integer value for non-primary field in django with postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, increment

I have a non-primary key integer field in my Django model and I use Postgresql for database.

```
class TestModel(models.Model)
    pid = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    some_field = models.CharField()
```

I want my pid field to have default values, that appear in database, I set the serial type for the pid field on the DB side

```
alter column pid type serial not null;
```

but when I create some record without without specifying value for pid, Django gives an error "null value in column "pid" violates not-null constraint", although it works fine when inserting data via SQL directly into database.
I found this [Django and PostgreSQL sequence for primary key autoincrement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008850/django-and-postgresql-sequence-for-primary-key-autoincrement/10008996), but it's not working for me

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields), you need to use `AutoField`. Like:

```
pid = models.AutoField(blank=true)
```

because what you change in database doesn't reflect to your Django immediately, better of changing your model and migrate your changes.

Comment: I tried this, but it says "AutoFields must set primary_key=True".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228034/django-non-primary-key-autofield well the other way is to do this. @dreamquester

Comment: yeah, I am thinking of this too, I created a method like this, but thought I could do it without additional methods, just on DB side. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the default values or use the AutoFiled.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#default

After making changes to your models, always use makemigrations and migrate to reflect the changes into the db.

Comment: It seems that there is no way to avoid inserting null value into a field, when saving a model object and I really have to use signals or create some method to generate a default value. Thanks